# Exporting Plot with suppressed error messages

Tags: graphics, export, warning-messages

I have generated a plot that has some error highlighting that I cannot get rid of. There does not seem to be a good way to do so, but it does not impact the actual plot itself. In order to display it I have used this code (from another SE post I have since lost) to suppress the error messages associated with the plot:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 AutoStyleOptions -> {"FormattingErrorStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
      RGBColor[1., 0.33, 0.33], 
     Background -> RGBColor[1., 0.33, 0.33, 0.15]},(*pink style*)
   "FormattingErrorTooltips" -> False,(*suppress tooltips*)
   "HighlightFormattingErrors" -> 
    False (*suppress error indication*)}]
```

However when I then try to export the plot with `Export` the error highlighting is still visible on the exported plot. Does anyone know how to suppress this behavior?

Comment: find and fix the error

Comment: Unfortunately the error appears to be burried in an external package I have no way of editting. Specifically it has to deal with using the MaTeX package for custom plot labels when combined with using scaling functions to generate Log axes. The error does not impact the look of the plot outside of the red shading.

Comment: With `plot` as your plot, export `Style[plot, AutoStyleOptions -> {"HighlightFormattingErrors" -> False}]`

Comment: So I had also tried this which allows plot to be rendered in the Mathematica GUI without the formatting highlights but still causes there to be highlights when exported.